# Declaring Global variable in Python Class

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do i declare global variable in python class. What i mean is : if i have a class like this

```
class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      myvaraible = "content"
     #do something

class UserPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #i want to access myvariable in this class
```

Comment: I think you want an instance variable. If you really need a global variable don't put it in the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use class variables for this, which are a bit cleaner solution than globals:

```
class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    myvariable = ""

    def get(self):
        HomePage.myvariable = "content"
```

You can access it with `HomePage.myvariable` again from other classes also.

To create an ordinary instance variable use this:

```
class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.myvariable = "content"
```

Answer (score 5):

Declare the variable global wherever you assign it

```
myvariable = None

class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
       global myvariable
       myvariable = "content"
```